# Why does $_GET return values but get_query_var does not?

Tags: query, query-variable

I have a bunch of query parameters that have been added with `add_filter( 'query_vars'`. I'm subsequently querying these with `get_query_var` like so:

```
$search = '' !== sanitize_text_field( get_query_var( $item['name'] ) ) ? array_push( $meta_query_array, array( 'key' => $item['name'], 'value' => sanitize_text_field( get_query_var( $item['name'] ) ), 'compare' => 'LIKE' ) ) : null;
```

No results are returned. If I use `$_GET` instead with the code block below, it works as desired.

```
if( isset( $_GET[ $item['name'] ] ) && ! empty( $_GET[ $item['name'] ] ) ) {
    $_GET[ $item['name'] ] ? array_push( $meta_query_array, array( 'key' => $item['name'], 'value' => sanitize_text_field( $_GET[ $item['name'] ] ), 'compare' => 'LIKE' ) ) : null;
}
```

- What am I doing incorrectly?
- Should I be using `$_GET` over `get_query_var`?
- Are there any trade-offs with using `$_GET` and not `get_query_var`?

Comment: How are you filtering `query_vars`? What's `$item`? Are you dynamically registering query vars?

Comment: URL parameters and query variables are not the same thing, e.g. `example.com/mypage` has no URL/GET parameters, but it does have a query variable named `pagename` that comes from rewrite rules, Calebs answer gets to the point of what that function does

Comment: @JacobPeattie, yes, I'm dynamically registering query vars.

Comment: @TomJNowell, I've posted a comment to clarify Caleb's answer. My understanding from your feedback is that if I'm passing parameters back to the main query and `$meta_query_array` from values submitted in a form and the URL parameters it generates, I should be using `  $_GET` instead?

Comment: @Motivated "*No results are returned*" - where/when/how are you running the code in question? Is it via a function which runs during the `pre_get_posts` action? What's your code for that and also this part - "*bunch of query parameters that have been added with `add_filter( 'query_vars'`*"? Because to me, *it sounded like you're calling `get_query_var()` **too early**, or that the query vars were not registered on the current page*.

Comment: @SallyCJ, I'm doing something very similar to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60618/sort-posts-by-custom-field-numeric-value-using-dropdown. The 2 primary differences are that instead of `filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'order', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING )`, I'm using calling `$search = '' !== sanitize_text_field( get_query_var( $item['name'] ) ) ? array_push( $meta_query_array, array( 'key' => $item['name'], 'value' => sanitize_text_field( get_query_var( $item['name'] ) ), 'compare' => 'LIKE' ) ) : null;` and secondly, the dropdown menu is dynamically generated.

Comment: You should've really just added your code and all relevant details to your post, because right now, since you are using the `pre_get_posts` action, then the most likely reason why "`$_GET` worked, but not `get_query_var()`", is because the query variables were not properly registered. You can confirm it by doing a `isset( $query->query_vars[ $item['name'] ] )` from within your `pre_get_posts` callback - if you get `false`, then the query var is likely unregistered, hence `get_query_var()` returned nothing.

Comment: @SallyCJ, `isset( $query->query_vars[ $item['name'] ] )` returns a value on the first page but is lost on the second or subsequent pages. I would expect `get_query_var()` to survive pagination without any additional changes to `pre_get_posts`

Comment: Yes, but you're *dynamically/conditionally* adding the query vars, so as I said, the query vars aren't being properly registered. But I can't help you further without looking at your code which is adding the custom query vars, however, you should post another question for getting help specifically with adding your query vars, if you wish to continue adding your form's filters as public query vars.

Comment: @SallyCJ, thanks. Will do. To help guide my understanding, is there any added advantage of using query vars over $_GET. I appreciate the details Caleb and Tom have shared but I'm not still entirely clear on when I should use $_GET and and query vars. If you could help clarify it in this post, that would be great. It would also assist me in formulating my follow-up post and question.

Comment: Well, that's a pretty subjective question, otherwise, I would have posted an answer. But regarding *public* query vars, one advantage is that the value is automatically read from the current request (e.g. the query string of the current URL) on page load. However, if I were you and just trying to control the arguments I'm passing to `WP_Query`, e.g. add a meta query if the user selected option X from a dropdown in my form, then I'd probably just read the data directly from `$_GET`, i.e. without having to register custom query vars.

Comment: You should also understand that `get_query_var( 'name' )` is really just a shorthand for `$GLOBALS['wp_query']->get( 'name' )`, or the direct-access version: `$GLOBALS['wp_query']->query_vars['name']`. So, the data is read from `$wp_query->query_vars`.

Comment: @SallyCJ, thanks. I'll be honest that I'm lost when I should consider using custom query variables. You are absolutely right that I'm simply passing back the values from a form to filter pre_get_posts and I'll stick with $_GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they do different things and source their data from different places.

`$_GET` is for URL parameters, values passed via HTTP GET. `get_query_var` is for fetching the query variables of the main post query aka the `WP_Query` object. **Query variables and GET values are not the same thing.**

Query variables usually get their values either from query objects, e.g. the parameters and arguments passed to `new WP_Query` or `get_posts`. Another place they can come from are rewrite rules. This may be where confusion is coming from as query variables can be set using URL parameters, but this does not mean that all URL parameters are query values. Query values can only have certain values.

### Should you use `get_query_var` to fetch URL parameters/GET values?

***No, you should not, that's not what that function is for.***

Instead use standard PHP methods such as `filter_input` or `$_GET`

### Notes on Query Variables

- Query variables have a whitelist, so `p` is a valid name for a query variable, but `banana` is not. There is a filter to add these but it's rarely used.

  - It's main use is when writing custom rewrite rules in order to pass information along, For example lets say I had a plugin to redirect to stack exchange answers that had `/?stackanswer=417665` and I wanted a pretty URL e.g.`/tomsanswers/417665`  where `417665` is a stack exchange ID, I'd add a rewrite rule with a regex to map that to `index.php?stackanswer=match[1]`, and I'll then look to see if the `stackanswer` query variable has a value, but I'd need to add `stackanswer` to the list of allowed query variables or it'll be stripped out. In this sitaution `$_GET['stackanswer']` would not exist
  - you can set query variables on any page via URL/GET variables because *ugly* permalinks take the form `index.php?queryvar=value`, and pretty permalinks are just regexes that turn pretty URLs into ugly ones. Note that with pretty permalinks those *ugly* URLs are purely hypothetical and internal, no redirects are happening, and no server mapping happens. It's not the same as doing it in an Apache/Nginx config, the URL hasn't actually changed. This is why you can add `?s=searchterm` to any archive in WP to search just that archive rather than the entire site.
- Query variables, or query *arguments* can be changed but you must do this *before* the query runs. An action is provided for this named `pre_get_posts` that will provide the query in question as a function argument.

  - Similar actions exist for terms/comments/users e.g. `pre_get_users`
  - these run for all queries, not just the main query, and not just the frontend
  - You can't use this action from a theme template if you want to modify the main query because it's too late and would require a small amount of time travel
  - If you have `query_posts` or `new WP_Query` at the top of every template, switching it to instead use `pre_get_posts` can provide huge performance boosts, and avoid lots of common errors, e.g. pagination problems

    - this also fixes RSS feeds not showing the right posts, 404's when your custom template has 10 pages but the original query only has 6 pages of content and the user requests page 7, etc etc

Comment: thanks for the added background. If I've understood you correctly, as `get_query_var` is for fetching the query variables of the main post query aka the WP_Query object, I'm assuming that any variables passed to it continue with other operations e.g. paging. If yes, would I need to do something along the lines of `$query->set( 'paged', get_query_var( 'paged' ) );`. Also, I didn't get `Query values can only have certain values`. What are `certain values`?

Comment: when the template is loaded the main query has already ran and fetched the post, so `$query->set` would change the value, but it would be like changing a shopping order after it's already been delivered. By certain values I mean there's a whitelist. E.g. `banana` is not the name of a query variable, and if I do this: `$q = new WP_Query( ['banana' => 'fruit' ] );` then test it with `echo $q->get( 'banana' );` it will not print `fruit` because `banana` was stripped out as invalid. If you want to use `set` to modify/change/adjust a query, you need to do it on `pre_get_posts` action

Comment: This means you can't change the page of a query from a template, and you can only pass certain parameters to a query object. There's a filter to add new ones, and it's primary use is for adding new query vars for custom rewrite rules. The `pre_get_posts` action lets you modify queries before they run, and the main query runs _before_ the template is loaded ( infact it's what WP uses to decide which template to load ). Query variables come from rewrite rules and the arguments passed to query objects ( `WP_Query`/`get_posts`/`get_pages` ). Sometimes query variables can be set via the URL.

Comment: URL parameters/GET variables are just standard GET variables, they're a part of the PHP language and aren't a WordPress feature. _Made some edits to the answer_, if it answers your question consider marking it as accepted/correct

Comment: thanks. Should query variables only be limited to rewrite rules and if I need to pass URL parameters, I should use GET instead?

Comment: as I mentioned in the answer, if you use URL parameters ( aka HTTP GET ) then you should not use query variables to read them, that would be a misuse of the API, GET variables aren't a WordPress thing, they're a PHP thing, don't overcomplicate that

Comment: thanks. The bit I'm a little unclear about is if URL parameters are passed as a result of a GET form request, is there any value in using add_filter( 'query_vars' for custom query variables. If I'm hearing you right, I should stick with URL parameters and GET.

Comment: I was pretty clear with my answer, re-read as there's an entire section that explicitly states both that question and the answer titled "Should you use get_query_var to fetch URL parameters/GET values?". GET variables are not WordPress, they're basic HTTP, a part of the foundation of the PHP programming language that WordPress is built on top of, and transcend even the programming language itself, they exist in other programming languages too. Query variables are unique to the WordPress code and APIs, as are filters, hooks, etc. GET != Query parameters

Comment: to reiterate, if you were to take the inputs in your form, and turn them into query variables so you could then use `get_query_var`, this would be an extreme abuse/misuse of the API, and very very bad practice. Query variables are not URL parameters, and they are not the WordPress version of `$_GET`. Form handling has nothing to do with query vars. It may make sense to think of them as `WP_Query` variables, as I still see that you're muddling it up URL parameters

Comment: thanks for the added clarification. I guess I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around when query_var, get_query_var and $_GET should be used. And the reason I may be mixing them up is because I'm passing the URL parameters to WP_Query to filter the results using pre_get_posts. So what I think I'm hearing and understanding is that I use $_GET when using a form to pass a bunch of values back to WP_Query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147487/discussion-between-motivated-and-tom-j-nowell).

Answer (score 1):

The `get_query_var()` is for accessing query vars on the main query, not for accessing parameters on the URL.

> Retrieves the value of a query variable in the `WP_Query` class.

Source: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/

Comment: To clarify, do you mean that if I want to pass parameters back from a form and URL to the main query  and `$meta_query_array`, I should be using `$_GET` instead? I'm super confused.

Comment: Reading through the details in https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/, it makes mention of the ability to query with get_query_var() custom query variables if they are registered

Comment: Query variables are the parameters passed to the main post query aka the main `WP_Query` object. URL parameters/GET variables come from query parameters in the URL e.g. `example.com/?parameter=value`. `get_query_var` does not read from the URL. It appears you've confused both of these as being the same system and the same data, when they are not, perhaps because some people refer to the URL parameters as the "query parameters", which is a coincidence